# Batch file to move folders to sub-folders

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, directory, move

Here is my current folder structure:

```
C:\Invoices\**CustomerName**\January
```

I'm looking for a script that will go through ALL the CustomerNames and move the January folder to

```
C:\Invoices\**CustomerName**\2013\January
```

Thanks

Comment: Try it yourself, follow this link and use the commands. It is much more satisfying to manage it yourself ;-) http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/batch.htm

Answer (score 4):

```
cd \invoices
for /d %%I in (*) do (
    md "%%I\2013"
    move "%%I\January" "%%I\2013"
)
```